# If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, isf $f'$ bounded on $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ is $f'$ bounded on $[a,b]$ ?

I'm not sure it's true because $f'$ is not supposed to be continuous, but I can't find a counter example. I recall that $f$ being absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ means that $\lim_{t\to a^+}f'(x)$ and $\lim_{t\to b^-}f'(x)$ exist.

Comment: You can take $f$ zero everywhere, with many little bumps that get close and close to $a$, that their height tends to zero (say, like $1/n^2$), but that their widths tend to zero way faster than their heights do (like $1/n!$). Rolle's theorem gives you that in the bumps there are points with derivatives that get larger and larger.

Comment: Can you explicitly state where you put those points while preserving continuity, @conditionalMethod?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Continuity? It is already done. Differentiability is the question, but you can just invoke Whitney's extension theorem to not have to write anything explicitly.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Continuity is not really the issue, because the height of the bumps goes to $0$. Differentiability works ok if you put bumps of height $n^{-2}$ on the points in the form $\frac1n$.

Comment: We can even have a strictly-increasing differentiable $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ such that $ f'$ is unbounded above on $[a,b].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let
$$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x = 0 \\
x^2\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2}) & x \ne 0
\end{cases}$$
This function is differentiable with
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x = 0 \\
2x\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2}) - \dfrac{2}{x} \cos(\dfrac{1}{x^2})  & x \ne 0
\end{cases}$$
To see this for $x=0$, note that $\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2}) = 0$.

Now clearly $f'(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}) = -2\sqrt{2 \pi n} \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider $x \mapsto x^2\sin\left(x^{-2}\right)$ on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

The examples above are good counterexamples. On the other hand if  $f \in C^1$ then since $[a,b]$ is compact so $f'[a,b]$ is likewise compact, therefore bounded.